# Remove file ext from batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hay i have search around here alot and try whole day to remove the file ext from path name

I try to do this after the B variable is set, but it won´t work, also when im asking are it somewhere i can tell in the foreach what folders it can loop in?

Now it loop in everything in that folder but i want it to loop in folder A-Z and no files in the working directory

/Mvh Lukasz

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Foreach files in folder
for /R . %%f in (*) do (

  :: Get file extension
  set A=%%~xf
  echo !A!

  :: Set path
  set B=%%f

  :: Remove file ext
  set D=!B:!A=%

  echo !D!

  :: Show result
  ::echo !D:%CD%\=!

  mkdir "%cd%\root\!B:%CD%\=!"
)

pause
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to do so I could try creating my own solution based from your code?

Comment: @konsolebox

I try to loop in directory know its lets say "C:/Dir" and in this dir its like "/A" "/B" "/C" and in there its random files i try to loop in this directorys and create folders after what files that are in all this dirs.

Whit other words if you have "/A/Somefile1.ext" and /B/someFile2.ext" the script should if it work create "A/Somefile1" and "B/someFile2" in "C:/Dir/root"

/ Lukasz

Comment: @konsolebox look at this example it works 100% but it won´t remove subdir http://pastebin.com/dDRadWgh

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" (
    set PREFIX=%CD:~0,-1%
) else (
    set PREFIX=%CD%
)
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /s/b') do (
    set N=%%~dpF%%~nF
    set N=!N:%PREFIX%=!
    if not "!N:~1,4!" == "root" (
        set N=%PREFIX%\root!N!
        if not exist "!N!" (
            mkdir "!N!"
        )
    )
)
```

Without subdirectories:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" (
    set PREFIX=%CD:~0,-1%
) else (
    set PREFIX=%CD%
)
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /s/b') do (
    set N=%%F
    set N=!N:%PREFIX%=!
    if not "!N:~1,4!" == "root" (
        set N=%PREFIX%\root\%%~nF
        if not exist "!N!" (
            mkdir "!N!"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: That was not the problem, the extension is in A variable, the problem is to get it to work whit "set D=!B:!A=%" so the file extension not are in the final command "mkdir "%cd%\root\!B:%CD%\=!" /Lukasz

Comment: that not working at all, have you try it yourself? It create dirs where it allredy is dirs seems like you miss my point

Comment: @Whiskey I didn't miss your point. I just made a mistake on how I test the directories.

Comment: i suggest you look at my code in http://pastebin.com/dDRadWgh and test it whit files in subdir under working directory to actully see what it does as your no way near it

Comment: @Whiskey I didn't copy that you were wanting to create create the files on another directory. Why not just tell what you wanted on anything that I missed rather than make me further examine your code?

Comment: im sorry i think that was quite clear actully that was why i have my code example, its an exact copy of work dir i try to do but change the files to dirs whitout filename, but even if i will have it in another dir the code above not working

Comment: its still not correct what part do you don´t get? Yes it create folders and yes it create it in root, but not full path, it create every folder in the root if folder is "A/This.txt" it should create "root/A/This/" and not "root/a/ and root/This", and that was clear in my last massage when i told it is a total copy of the path only that it change the files to folders whitout ext \ Whiskey

Comment: @Whiskey That's exactly what the first answer is doing. I just included the second answer just in case I was mistaken because you kept saying misleading directions like *but it won´t remove subdir*. You see you don't really care about trying the answers at all.

Comment: That awsome! Sorry for that i missed it totally was tierd last night and looked and thinked the subdirs was the last one and not first, my misstake anyway it works awsome! Thanks alot, now just last thing as i asked if you can set what dir it allowed to foreach or does it has to repost the code over and over for every dir? like only allow "A|B|C|D" all other folders are ignored \Whiskey

Comment: I have try to slove the if question but whatever i do i won´t work or ignore other things. My example is above of what i have try done

Comment: $konsolebox Looks like it got removed, you can find it here anyways http://pastebin.com/p5Q1LaTF \Whiskey

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for /R "%cd%" %%a in (*) do for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do (
        if not exist "%cd%\root\%%~nb\%%~na\" echo mkdir "%cd%\root\%%~nb\%%~na"
    )
```

If the output to console is correct, remove the `echo` to create the folders

Comment: That create more then it has to, but yeh it quite close, it create the current dir, that it not has to, only sub dirs, also is it any way as i asked before to set what dirs it can check? Try something like this "for /R "%cd%" %%a in ("%CD%\A\*") do for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do ("

Comment: look at this example it works 100% but it won´t remove subdir http://pastebin.com/dDRadWgh –  Whiskey